# WPF multi-button backgroundcolor change

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, ivalueconverter, wpf-brushes

```
<Button Content="1" Background="{Binding HotNumbers, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}  }"/>
<Button Content="2" Background="{Binding HotNumbers, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}  }"/>
```

..

I have 10 buttons. I am trying to bind the background color of each to an `ObservableCollection<bool>`. I tried using a `IValueConverter` to convert the boolean value to a Brush color as below.

But the whole collection seems to be passed in the object value instead of single item throwing an exception in the converter.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
             if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                return Brushes.White;
            }
        }
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this so that I don't have to create 10 different properties for each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will work just with this:

```
<Button Content="1" Background="{Binding HotNumbers[0], Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}"/>
<Button Content="2" Background="{Binding HotNumbers[1], Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: You're wellcome @tarzan, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply add the ConverterParameter in your xaml code like this?

**Background="{Binding HotNumbers, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, ConverterParameter=1  } "**

and then in your converter you use your object parameter to access the specific boolean item of your array like this?

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value[(int)parameter])
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            return Brushes.White;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The casting doesn't work. Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'